# How to automatically refresh data when opening Excel document using existing ODBC connection?

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

Already created an ODBC connection to get data from a file in our SQL server. It works fine when executing the ODBC in Excel manually.

Now I would like to have an Excel file that automatically, on opening, executes that ODBC connection and updates the data. But I don't know how to start my VBA code.

Comment: I think you'll find an abundance of information on the net.  What have you tried so far?  Did google's VBA free solution not do the job? https://www.google.com/search?q=refresh+query+table+on+opening+excel&oq=refresh+query+table+on+openeing+exce&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j33l6.12623j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SQL server admin privileges that would allow you to create stored procedures? If so, then you can create a query that can be externally linked to your excel document.

If that is not available to you, I would suggest re-creating the SQL query within VBA. If you only need a specific range of data (say within a date range or certain product) then you could modify the command text of the ODBC connection to your liking under the Data ribbon. Additionally, the file can refresh the data upon opening the file if the checkbox "Refresh data when opening the file" has been ticked in the Connection Properties.